# Does any way to run a .net core project on IIS using Jetbrains Rider?

Tags: .net, .net-core, jetbrains-ide, rider

I can't run dotnet core project on IIS using Rider. I Couldn't find any solution to do that. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: I'm using Windows 10 BTW.

Comment: https://rider-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360003163200-Debug-through-IIS There are still open issues in this area, so your only hope is that JetBrains invests more to close the gaps.